# How to delete host name site collection

Tags: 2013, site-collection, delete

How can I delete a host named Site Collection?

Its 2013 SharePoint Foundation. I tried to create few but they didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do this using SharePoint Central Administration Site or using PowerShell

```
Remove-SPSite -Identity "<URL>" -GradualDelete
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262392(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I cannot delete from site collection the delete button is greyed out

Comment: Try with PowerShell.